# Time based OTP produces different result from same key

Tags: micropython, totp, rp2040

For a two-factor authentication system I generate a base32 key and use it to generate a time based OTP every 30 seconds using the same key. I used [this code](https://github.com/nehadubey10/TOTP_GENERATION) on a Badger 2040 in MicroPython.

On Windows and Linux this generates the same OTP from the same key (tested using [this site](https://totp.danhersam.com/)). But on a Badger 2040 it generates a different OTP from that same key. Why?

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game I know, but this might help  others.

### Possible cause for out of sync code generation

From what I understand, [OTP uses a synchronised time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password#Time-synchronized) to generate the code, and a quick glance at your code shows that you don't set the time [before using it](https://github.com/nehadubey10/TOTP_GENERATION/blob/master/device_otp.py#L31) in `otp()`, thus your generated code on the 2040 is based on the default [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch) (IIRC that's **Jan 1st 2021 00:00:00.00** by default on a RPI pico).

### Setting the time with an RTC object

To set the time you can use [micropython's machine RTC class](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.RTC.html#class-rtc-real-time-clock) to set the time like so (reproduced from linked doc):

```py
rtc = machine.RTC()
rtc.datetime((2020, 1, 21, 2, 10, 32, 36, 0))
print(rtc.datetime())
```

`(2020, 1, 21, 2, 10, 32, 36, 0)` is a tuple of length 8 with the following format:

`(year, month, day of month, timezone, hour, minutes, seconds, miliseconds)`

### Caveat

Note that if you don't have a [battery backed RTC module like a DS3231 or a DS1307](https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2020/07/07/raspberry-pi-rtc-tutorial-using-ds1307-and-ds3231-rtcs-with-raspberry-pi-m/), it means the rp2040 will lose track of the time as soon as it looses power and it will have to be set again.
An alternative to using a battery backed RTC module is have the rp2040's RTC automatically synced when plugged via USB either with a [python script](https://web.archive.org/web/20221222135909/https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=146&t=300275#p1810708) or alternatively, by using [rshell](https://github.com/dhylands/rshell), which automatically sets the date/time, e.g:

```
$ rshell exit
Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 (buffer-size 512)...
Trying to connect to REPL  connected
Retrieving sysname ... rp2
Testing if sys.stdin.buffer exists ... Y
Retrieving root directories ... 
Setting time ... Dec 22, 2022 16:02:28
Evaluating board_name ... pyboard
Retrieving time epoch ... Jan 01, 1970
```